# Can I update AWS website with a local JSON file?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, web, localhost

I have a static [website](http://xuanrongmusic.com/) currently hosted on AWS and I suppose its static (i.e. I can't update it without manually changing the HTML and then reuploading to AWS).  I want to make it easier for myself to update certain sections (particularly the 'dates' section).  So I was thinking of using a JSON object.  Ideally the AWS website would be able to update from a JSON file on my local/personal computer but I'm not sure if that's possible?  Do I need the JSON file to be uploaded to a web server/AWS every time I change it?  I would like to just update my JSON file locally and not have to change/update anything in AWS.  Is this possible or do I need some type of API?

Comment: Why don't you use  https://jekyllrb.com managing your static site?

Comment: If you think about it for a minute, the answer should become apparent:  how would a local file influence the behavior of a web site that is accessible from anywhere on earth, given the reasonably safe assumption that it is impossible for anyone else to access your local file?

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from your question, I can think of the below two use-cases:

1) In case your static website is hosted on S3, you can use the AWS CLI (Command Line Interface): https://aws.amazon.com/cli/. This will allow you to upload the files directly from your local machine to the S3 bucket.

2) In case it is hosted on an EC2 Instance, you can setup a git repository for your website and push the changes made to the git server. The same git server can then be used to pull the latest changes on your EC2 instance.